# Android data/view binding vs findViewById for performance

Tags: android, data-binding

I realize the potential for android data binding for MVVM is great and it opens doors.  Likewise for view binding. But regarding performance, is data/view binding faster then using findViewById  in native android ?

Comment: FYI, you mention *Data Binding* but I think your question refers to *View Binding*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks to me that it is faster per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#data_binding_layout_files):

> > Views With IDs
>
> A public final field will be generated for each View with an ID in the
> layout. The binding does a single pass on the View hierarchy,
> extracting the Views with IDs. This mechanism can be faster than
> calling findViewById for several Views.

So it seems data binding only has to do a single pass over the view hierarchy instead of us always calling findViewById.

Comment: You can do the same without databinding. Just a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: There is potential for data binding to be much faster with its single pass through the hierarchy, but if you only only care about one View and do findViewById just once, it won't save you anything. There are several other systems available that do similar things to avoid the findViewById. Android data binding gives this to you as a side benefit because it also has to scan the hierarchy to find all its views to set all the bindings. Kind of a nice side benefit, really.

Comment: Correct, George - especially if the only view you're interested in is high up in the hierarchy it's fast to find it and go on.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: When I call findViewById 3 times in a row, it traverses the view hierarchy 3 times. Data binding cuts this down to 1 (per layout)?

Comment: Can anyone produce some metircs to show how much faster data/view binding is than findViewById?

Answer (score 1):

Databinding is really faster compared to findViewById and setText .
Not only performance, It is also much faster and maintainable for mid, full-scale projects. As a side note, benefits include:

- performance
- logic extraction from ui
- code minimalization using livedata
- testability
- readability
- avoiding null pointer exception when view is null(I love this feature)
- custom property declaration in xml
- updating multiple properties simultaneously

In a nutshell, Databinding is a really cool feature.
To learn about these features, you can visit codelabs here:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#0