# Which way of using DataBinding is faster

Tags: android, performance, android-databinding

I understood that DataBinding can be significantly faster than `findViewById`.
This was f.e. explained here: [Android data binding vs findViewById for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712820/android-data-binding-vs-findviewbyid-for-performance)

I'm now wondering which of the following options is faster:

**Option A**

xml:

```
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/my_text_view"/>
```

usage:

```
mBinding.myTextView.setText("DummyText")
```

**Option B**

xml:

```
 <variable
     name="dummy"
     type="String" />

 ...
 <TextView
     android:text="@{dummy}"/>
```

usage:

```
mBinding.setDummy("DummyText")
```

Comment: Why downvoting without reasoning? What aspect is bad to reason a downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Just because you view the two options as perfect substitutes, you trying to minimize the cost (in speed) even if the difference is essentially unperceivable from the result.

The fact is that even if the result is the same for both options, the second could give you more flexibility in the future when you decide(very probable) to use a ViewModel and LiveData, because they give you many benefits for little adjustments to the code.

So for example, you could create a view model with all the MutableLiveData:

```
public class MyVM extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<String> title = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<String> text = new MutableLiveData<>();
}
```

set the entire viewmodel as variable in the xml and use your variables directly:

```
mBinding.setNiceViewModel(myVM);

<variable
     name="niceViewModel"
     type="MyVM" />

 ...
 <TextView
     android:text="@{niceViewModel.title}"/>

<TextView
     android:text="@{niceViewModel.text}"/>
```

Comment: I do use ViewModel and LiveData. But in the observer I could still call either of the two options, correct? Your suggestion is basically more convinient, but in terms of speed it is really the same?

Comment: your answer is pretty vague yourself, you have not said why it's good and why it's better, it simply should be presumed better because reasons.